# Error while saving JSON data to Firestore collection using cloud function

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to insert array in my firebase collection from cloud function. I need to have multiple lines in one document so for each line i am inserting an array. Please check my attached screenshot where you can see line0 , same way i need to have Line1,Line2,Line3..,Line n in the same document.

for line0 i am passing array from code like below and its working fine.

```
admin.firestore().collection("qbContestWinners").add(
        {
            'cmpientryid': context.params.processId,
            'qbid': '',
            'qbsyncdate': '',
            'qbsyncstatus': 'pending',
            'Line0':
            {
                id: "0",
                description: 'PRIZE AMOUNT',
                amount: 1000,
                accountrefid: contestresultData.qbcontestid,
                accountrefname: contestresultData.qbcontestname,
                contestresultId: context.params.processId,
            },
        })
```

when i am looping through data i am getting from another table , i am not able to generate proper JSON to insert.

below is how i am looping and creating JSON after getting data from another table.

```
   i = 1;
            admin.firestore().collection("results").where('cid', '==', 'LKRRk2XXXXXXXX')
            .orderBy("rank", "asc").get().then(snapshots =>
                        {
                            snapshots.forEach(doc =>
                                {
                                    const contestresultId = doc.id;
                                    const prizeAmount = doc.data().prizeamt;
                                    const userId = doc.data().userid;
                                    const lineNum = "Line" +  i;
                                    console.log("new line numner is: ", lineNum);
                                    console.log(`lineNum? ${lineNum}`);

                                    const linetxt = "Line" + String(i);
                                    const insertData = "{"+linetxt +
                                                        ":{id:'" + i +
                                                         "', description: 'PRIZE AMOUNT'"+
                                                           ", amount:" + prizeAmount + "," +
                                                           "accountrefid:"+ contestresultData.qbcontestid +","+
                                                           "accountrefname:'" +contestresultData.qbcontestname +"',"+
                                                           "contestresultId:'" + contestresultId +"'," +
                                                       "},}"
                                      const finalInsert = JSON.stringify(insertData);
                                      const finalJSON = JSON.parse(finalInsert);
                                       admin.firestore().collection("qbContestWinners").doc(mainID).set(

                                         finalInsert.toJSON(),

                                    {
                                        merge: true
                                    });

                                i= i+1;
                            });
            });
```

using this code i am getting error
**finalInsert.toJSON is not a function**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `Line0` field is a map and not an Array, see this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) for more details.

So, if you want to create similar fields (`Line1`, `Line2`, ...), you simply need to pass a JavaScript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method, as follows:

```
snapshots.forEach(doc => {
        const contestresultId = doc.id;
        const prizeAmount = doc.data().prizeamt;
        const userId = doc.data().userid;
        const lineNum = "Line" +  i;
        console.log("new line numner is: ", lineNum);
        console.log(`lineNum? ${lineNum}`);

        const lineObj = {
            id: i,
            description: 'PRIZE AMOUNT',
            accountrefid: contestresultData.qbcontestid,   //Not sure if you have defined contestresultData somewhere...
            //...
        }

        const dataObj = {};
        dataObj["Line" + i] = lineObj   // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

        admin.firestore().collection("qbContestWinners").doc(mainID).set(dataObj, {merge: true});

        i= i+1;
});
```

---

**HOWEVER**, note that you must return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work in your Cloud Function is complete (i.e. call to the Firestore `set()` method).

*This is explained in the official Firebase [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/), watch in particular the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises".*

Since you are calling several times the `set()` method in a `forEach` loop, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to return a Promise when all these parallel calls to the `set()` method are completed.

The following should do the trick:

```
let i = 1;
return admin.firestore().collection("results")    // <-- See the return here
.where('cid', '==', 'LKRRk2XXXXXXXX')
.orderBy("rank", "asc").get()
.then(snapshots => {
    const promises = [];

    snapshots.forEach(doc => {
            const contestresultId = doc.id;
            const prizeAmount = doc.data().prizeamt;
            const userId = doc.data().userid;
            const lineNum = "Line" +  i;


            const lineObj = {
                id: i,
                description: 'PRIZE AMOUNT',
                accountrefid: contestresultData.qbcontestid,
                //...
            }

            const dataObj = {};
            dataObj[lineNum] = lineObj;

            promises.push(admin.firestore().collection("qbContestWinners").doc(mainID).set(dataObj, {merge: true}));

        i= i+1;
    });

    return Promise.all(promises)  // <-- See the return here
});
```

---

**A last remark:** if `mainID` keeps the same value in the `snapshots.forEach` loop, you may adopt a totally different approach, consisting in building a JavaScript object with several `LineXX` properties and call the `set()` method only once. Since you didn't share the entire code of your Cloud Function it is impossible to say if this approach should be used or not.

Comment: I used same approach which you have suggested in your remark because my "mainID" variable is keeping same value. thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

**first to the error**

You stringify and parse a string. The problem here seems to be the order. You have to parse a "String" and to stringify an "Object". The result won't have a toJSON Method as well, but u can just stringify the Object to get a json.

**the second thing**

Why do you use a string to create your object? You shouldn't. Just use an object.

**the third thing**

You should not use Objects as Arrays. Not even in firebase.

Just use arrays. Example:

`[Line0Object, Line1Object, ...]`

Hint: If your array can work as its own collection. Just use a SubCollection. This might fit your needs.